# Is it normal to have 400~600ms of waiting for first byte?

Tags: performance, page-speed, loading

I have optimized my website and apply many advices found on the Google search. but finally i have about 400~600ms of time to first byte. Does it normal or I can lower it?

For dynamic data it it about 500~600ms base on the code that creates the content.

I think it must be lower for static files but for static files it hit the 400ms of time to first byte. why?

Using Apache2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 VPS

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TTFB between 400 - 600 ms may be normal for non-optimized servers / code, but it certainly is not the best you can get. You can optimize your server with Nginx, Varnish, HHVM or Redis (or multiple) to make both static content and dynamic content load faster.

But don't look only at the TTFB, there are other numbers that matter.

Comment: yes you're right, i have latency (280ms on average) problem! but my site is optimised! webpagetest.org reports TTFB of 350ms

Comment: 280 ms latency is extreme, you should never have such numbers (unless on satellite / mobile internet)

Comment: Ping statistics for x.x.x.x:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 222ms, Maximum = 241ms, Average = 230ms

Comment: compare it with Google for example (8.8.8.8) to see where the problem is

Comment: Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 172ms, Maximum = 184ms, Average = 178ms

Comment: Thats high. I would recommend doing some more tests to figure out what is causing that latency

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  If in doubt, try checking the time to first byte of  popular websites in your market, or take a look at this article :  https://moz.com/blog/improving-search-rank-by-optimizing-your-time-to-first-byte

If your ttfb is between 400-600ms, you have nothing to worry about on that score.

Although you may possibly be able to shave off a few ms, if you are doing this because you have one website and want it to be fast for users and perform well in search engines, then there are almost certainly other more useful areas you could be working on.

Comment: thanks, i check my site with webpagetest.org and get 350ms of TTFB! and googled about why it is reports other than my test, so find it is the latency problem, i have ping my site from here and get 280ms on average. it is better to change my server physical place to remove this huge latency!

Comment: That might help, but: 280ms is about 85000km in speed-of-light terms, so distance alone can't explain that.  Since your latency to google's 8.8.8, which is anycast (and therefore fairly-local-everywhere), approaches 200ms, it seems likely to me that your internet connection is very poor: either via a poor connection, or through an oversubscribed provider, or both.  If this is so, moving the server won't help you all that much.